# Backup sqlserver 2019 and restore to Sqlserver 2017

Tags: backup, restore, ssms, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

I have only 1 table in SqlServer 2019 that I want to backup and restore into SqlServer 2017 in different server.

To SqlServer 2019 I have access to server and with SSMS but to SqlServer2017 I have access only with SSMS

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A backup is overkill for only one table and I'm not sure what compatibility issues you can run into restoring to a lower version of SQL Server (since backups occur at the database level).

Instead you should look to just copy the data between servers. There are a multitude of ways and tools out there to help you do this, but I've always found the [SQL Examiner Suite](https://www.sqlaccessories.com/sql-examiner-suite/) simple enough for such a task. They offer a fully functional 30 day free trial, so you can utilize it as you need.

Alternatively you can setup a [**Linked Server**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) between the two instances and then can easily pull the data across the linked server to fill the table on your other instance, as needed.

Finally, you can also [export the data to a flat file](https://www.sqlshack.com/export-data-sql-server-flat-file/) from your SQL Server 2019 instance, and import that flat file using the same tool in **SSMS** on your SQL Server 2017 instance.

Outside of those options, you can also use [**BCP**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/bulk-import-and-export-of-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) as recommended by Bob Klimes, or you can [generate scripts with the data](https://www.nuttyabouthosting.co.uk/knowledgebase/article/how-to-generate-database-scripts-with-data-in-sql-server) as this article walks you through.

Here's the key steps you need, to include the **data** with the **schema** scripts when you use the **Generate Scripts** feature:

> (On the Set Scripting Options page) Click on the 'Advanced' button.

> Scroll down and select 'Schema and Data' from the 'Types of data to script' dropdown.

Comment: additional info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/bulk-import-and-export-of-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @BobKlimes Yup, thanks for linking **BCP** as an option as well, that's also valid. There's probably another half-dozen or so ways you can do this for just a single table as well OP, hopefully any of the ones we suggested so far work out.

Comment: @J.D. I guess  that `export the data to a flat file` is the most simple and easy way to do that

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom Probably, they each have their pros and cons, so it's subjective. But exporting and importing is relatively simple. The first solution using **SQL Examiner Suite** is very easy too if you only need to do this one time

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom I also updated my answer with additional options after reading your comments on the other answer. It is possible to script both the **schema** and the **data** together with the **Generate Scripts** feature in **SSMS**, as described in the walkthrough I linked.

Comment: @J.D. How can I upload the file that generate from `generate scripts with the data` to the new DB?

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom You can open the script (.SQL) file it generated in SQL Server Management Studio, connect to your new database server, and run the script like any other SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

You generally do not do it. It is not possible.

SQL Server is not forward compatible. 2017 does not know how to handle a 2019 backup. PERIOD - no discussion, it will tell you so.

Which is why it is an utterly stupid idea no to use the same versions over the whole application development team cycle - you make copy operations complex, you run into compatibility issues.

If you really have to do bit, export a generation script and run that - backup is NOT possibly with a restore on an older sql server version.

Comment: I have to do it... generation script will only build that scheme, not copy the content of table

Comment: Well, it does not matter what you "have to do" - it is not supported. PERIOD. Pigs can not fly, cars are not submarines and SQL Server will not restore a backup made with a later version.

Comment: @TomTom Agree with the Sql Server bit but this will challenge "cars are not submarines", even back in 1983 https://www.abc.net.au/news/2023-07-22/underwater-drive-darwin-harbour-aims-for-new-world-record/102622048 https://youtu.be/rNLL0fo9apc?si=CqjkzqkLD_XFnco0

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the scripts from SSMS and include the data. See [this](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/details/import-and-export-sql-database-to-.sql-script-via-sql-management-studio). This is what I would do if I needed a one time move of the schema and the data.